# Can I use net.TCP along with GZip technology in WCF

Tags: wcf, compression, gzip, http-compression, net.tcp

Can we use net.TCP binding to implement GZip in WCF or it can only be configured with Http and WsHttp bindings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't believe WCF supports GZip encoding using a TCP socket binding, however there is nothing stopping you sending GZiped compressed data over the wire, and manually compressing it using the methods built into the .NET framework: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream.aspx.

Before you go down this route however, I would strongly recommend assesing other performance enhancing measures on your TCP services as detailed here: [Transmitting the least amount of data over the wire with WCF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347423/transmitting-the-least-amount-of-data-over-the-wire-with-wcf)

Answer (score 5):

Wcf 4.5 RC support message encoder out of box
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751889(v=vs.110).aspx